# How to find the physical location of a git repo on Stash server?

Tags: git, git-stash

Given Stash URL,

```
http://stash.abc.net/scm/gui/something.git
```

How do I know the physical location of this repo? I am looking to find a directory to which I can `cd` to

EDIT: What is not clear please?

Comment: Do you mean in the file system?

Comment: @JelleDetaeye correct. On a file system

Comment: I don't think it's possible without having ssh access to that machine.

Comment: Right. I have access to that box. Now that I am on it, how can I find out the path to my repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repositories are stored in Stash using a unique ID number instead of their name. To determine the ID of a repository, navigate to the repository in Stash and select Settings, under Repository details, the repository's location on disk will be listed with the ID.

Once you have the Id the repository is located in *STASH_HOME/shared/data/repositories/*

Source Stash documentation: [Identifying a Repository on the Stash Server](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASHKB/Identifying+a+Repository+on+the+Stash+Server)

Comment: Our directory structure looks different. `find` by the id revealed nothing as well. Sigh. Any other ideas?